# Auth0 throws Callback URL mismatch when accessing Angular SPA deployed on Nginx on EC2

Tags: angular, nginx, auth0, callbackurl, auth0-deploy-cli

I currently have my Angular app running on Nginx within an EC2.  I did this so that I could create a Self-Signed SSL Certificate so that  Auth0 would recognize it as a "secure origin".

Now I have my app successfully running at `https://my_server_IP`, but every time I click Auth0 sign-in, which previously worked when I was running it locally, I get the following message:

> Callback URL mismatch. 
> The provided redirect_uri is not in the list of allowed callback URLs. 
> Please go to the Application Settings page and make sure you are sending a valid callback url from your application.

I have changed the following lines in in `auth_config.json`:

```json
{
  "domain": "my-account.us.auth0.com",
  "clientId": "my-client-id",
  "audience": "{API_IDENTIFIER}",
  "apiUri": "http://localhost:3001",
  "appUri": "http://localhost:4200",
  "errorPath": "/error"
}
```

...to this (after passing `index.html` to Nginx server deployed on EC2 and enabling SSL certs following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04)):

```json
{
  "domain": "my-account.us.auth0.com",
  "clientId": "my-client-id",
  "audience": "{API_IDENTIFIER}",
  "apiUri": "https://my_server_IP",
  "appUri": "https://my_server_IP",
  "errorPath": "/error"
}
```

My question is: is it even possible to use Auth0 if this app is running on Nginx on an EC2 instance?

Are there any other steps I need to take besides going to the Application Settings page and making  sure that I'm sending a valid callback url from my application? (I'm waiting on a fellow dev to log in and do this, as I'm currently working on the deployment of the frontend which works except for the Auth0).

Comment: The uri you use in your Angular app **must** match what is configured on Auth0. So updating the Application Settings should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Just had to add the exact URL (`https://my_server_IP`) to the list of valid callback URI's in Auth0 dashboard.

Additionally, there was no use for the `appUri` or `apiUri` fields in `auth_config.json`.  My `auth_config.json` file still looks like this (no changes except deleting the unused props):

```json
{
  "domain": "my-account.us.auth0.com",
  "clientId": "my-client-id",
  "audience": "{API_IDENTIFIER}",
  "errorPath": "/error"
}
```